# Highlight special word in a TextBox

Tags: wpf, syntax, textbox, highlight

How do I highlight all occurrences of a list of words in a text.
For example, i do have a list of strings ("if", "else", "then", "while", "true").
I do need to find them in a TextBox and highlight them (foreground + background color).

Examples as how it should look:
[image]
[image]

The current approach is to override TextBox and do "something" in the OnTextChange event.

Comment: For more advanced formatting I ended up going with a FlowDocument and FlowDocumentReader.  Different syntax but I found marking up the FlowDocument more logical.  You have to parse out the words then mark up the words.  If you want to stay with text consider a RichTextBox.  The model for  is different as you mark up positions in the RichTextBox (as opposed to the FlowDocument source).  Down side is a FlowDocument is complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm actually using some approaches using the RichTextBox but im making steps slowly.
Realized how i mark things there are still some bugs. For instance, everything gets
marked after the first character to mark. So it looks just like that:
[image]

```
pos is the position of the character i want to mark (+1 for just one character), in OnTextChange
MarkForeground(pos + 2, pos + 2 + 1, Colors.Green); // +2 for some awkward wpf bug probably ;)

private void MarkForeground(int start, int end, Color col)
    {
        TextPointer startPointer = this.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(start);
        TextPointer endPointer = this.Document.ContentStart.GetPositionAtOffset(end);

        if (startPointer != null && endPointer != null)
        {

            TextRange range = new TextRange(startPointer, endPointer);


            range.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(col));

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

see this question:

[How to highlight portion of a Rich TextBox WPF control if there are more than 2 spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924553/how-to-highlight-portion-of-a-rich-textbox-wpf-control-if-there-are-more-than-2-s)

and this open source control:

http://wpfsyntax.codeplex.com/